# Deezer API - Pegando valores do Json e PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando pegar algumas informações da API, consegui filtrar algumas coisas, mas por exemplo, estou tentando chegar no link 'preview' para tocar 30 segundos de música e não consigo chegar, fiz isso até agora :

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.deezer.com/2.0/search?q=Alok';
$jsonStr = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);

$album = array();



foreach ($jsonArr['data'] as $row) {
    $album[] = $row['album'];//['cover_xl'];

}

echo '<pre>'.print_r($album, true).'</pre>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui, na verdade, o acesso é direto.

```
foreach ($jsonArr['data'] as $row) {
    $album[] = $row['preview'];//['cover_xl'];

}
```